How to display splash screen during initial extraction phase of single-file exe
I have a WinForms application that is bundled as a single file exe. During the first launch on a new system, it always takes about 20 seconds for the exe to finish extracting all necessary files to a temp location before actually launching.
Is there any way to better convey to the users that the application is indeed starting up besides the cursor spinning for a long time? Preferably I would like to display a splash screen of some sort, but anything that doesn't look like a stuck process would already help.

I would recommend creating an installer (either .msi or .exe), where you can then even customize splash screen of some sort....
The way your application is bundled obviously did not take that into account.
You can create an installer using free software like ActualInstaller or NSIS, and you can customize your splash screen during the first launch on a new system (installation).
Naturally, subsequent starting of the application would then no longer require extracting all necessary files, as they would be installed already...
I hope it helps!
